# Toggle and Modals are not working on Angular app

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, angular7, angular-bootstrap-toggle

I am new to Angular and having some issues with getting Bootstrap toggle and Modal to work. BootStrap CSS files are working because the form is picking up the styling; however, I reckon JS files are not being linked properly. Please let me know what am I doing working.

I did an NPM install of BootStrap and jQuery using the Angular CLI.
Once installed, I linked the BootStrap and jQuery files to the angular.json file for the application to be able to use the libraries.

```
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/LyndaChapter1",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            **"styles": [
              **"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "src/styles.css"**
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
            ],**
            "es5BrowserSupport": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
```

Expected result: Toggle and Modals should work
Actual result: Neither are working

Comment: Have you tried putting the jquery dep first? Bootstrap is dependent on jquery, so it needs to load first.

Comment: Rather than relying on jQuery which you should avoid, there is already a bootstrap angular components packages you can use.

Comment: @Jacquesジャック, thanks for that, I reckon your suggestion did the trick.

Comment: I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with the other answers here about not using jQuery, if you are going to use it with bootstrap, or any other library that *depends* on it, you must load jQuery **first**.

So, to fix your issue, simple put the jQuery dependency above the bootstrap dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these packages to your package.json file and run npm install --save command on Package.json file level.

/* "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1" */

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a bad choice to run on Angular... what you may need is [ngBootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home)

There is excellent boilerplate code there which you can use just like [i did here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h8dynf)

relevant **HTML**:

```
<ng-template #content let-modal>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Profile update</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="dateOfBirth">Date of birth</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input id="dateOfBirth" class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp" ngbDatepicker #dp="ngbDatepicker">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" (click)="dp.toggle()" type="button"></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="modal.close('Save click')">Save</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>

<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open(content)">Launch demo modal</button>

<hr>

<pre>{{closeResult}}</pre>

<hr/>

<p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"
          [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Toggle
  </button>
</p>
<div id="collapseExample" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      You can collapse this card by clicking Toggle
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

relevant **TS**:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-basic',
  templateUrl: './modal-basic.html'
})
export class NgbdModalBasic {
  closeResult: string;
  public isCollapsed = false;

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title'}).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }

  private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
      return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {
      return  `with: ${reason}`;
    }
  }
}
```